# Remove form elements from pdf with their value remain at their place in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf, zend-pdf

I have a pdf which contain different form elements i want to remove these form elements with PHP but their value should be their..

or if i can some how disable the form element from header..???

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: This is called form flattening.

Comment: I have tried different libraries like fpdf,tcpdf etc but they doesn't provide such think i don't know what to do..